# keep getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with maven

Tags: java, jar, jsoup

I try to run a jar file, but without success. I know, that there are another answers, but I cannot understand, why with my IDE it runs perfectly but from a jar file not.

How can I change the dependency path? can use for it my ide?
My code you can find bellow:

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Busstation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>target/dependency-jars/jsoup-1.13.1.jar</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Exception

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    at DVBService.getAllDepartures(DVBService.java:15)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: do you have any other version of `org.jsoup` jar added in you buildpath? sometimes it creates problem

Comment: @AbhiN I added a photo from my directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, although I am not sure how this magic happens, I will try to explain myself. 
The only think that I needed to is make a fat jar.

There are apparently a lot of ways to do that :  [look up here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

So, here I just added another plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Im starting to really hate Jars cause this solution worked fine for years and now on a new project this isn't working!

Comment: In case someone comes here from Google like I did, make sure to add packages <mainClass> (i.e org. example.main etc)